# Will environment variables set in ~/.bash_profile on Windows 10 apply system-wide?

Tags: bash, windows-10

so yesterday (August 2nd, 2016) Microsoft released their Anniversary Update which brought, among other things, a fully fledged bash shell to Windows. Here's what I am wondering, when we use the command prompt in bash mode, can I create/update a .bash_profile as I would on a Mac and have those changes be system wide? Or, do I still have to use the advanced system settings whenever I need to set a variable like JAVA_HOME.

I tried to google it, but seeing as this is only a 1 day old update it is expected that there is no answer.

Comment: Mind going to [\[ super user \]](http://superuser.com) with this question ? ;)

Comment: I never heard of super user, and as such am uncertain of clicking said link. What is super user?

Comment: Super User is a question and answer site for computer enthusiasts and power users. It's built and run by you as part of the [\[ Stack Exchange \]](http://stackexchange.com/) network of Q&A sites.

Comment: Ah, gotcha, I see it is part of the stack exchange family Okay, thank you.

Comment: ...if by "system-wide" you mean applying to normal Windows programs, then no, `.bash_profile` changes won't apply system-wide.

Comment: Gotcha. Thank you very much. If so, could we still run/install specific programs that do have the option of being operated on via the command line, but which are not supported for Windows? I am trying to figure out the extent of this new feature's capability.

Comment: @SomeStudent You are continuing to ask questions that are off-topic on Stack Overflow. Please go to superuser.com.